# How to find the average of longitude and latitude positions?

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, latitude-longitude

Using Windows Phone 7 and Bing maps I'm trying to draw a nice looking track from GPS coordinates. In WP7, the GPS is providing me with the latest data but it is not as  accurate as I want.  I would like to take the average of last 'X' measurements. The problem is that position data is longitude and latitude and I am not sure I can compute the proper average of the position: (longitude1 + longitude2)/2 , (latitude1 + latitude2)/2

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with that? You should just define how many you want to use to determine the avg.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is a smoothing of the data.  I would suggest a simple low pass filter:

```
x_k = (1 - b) * x_k + b * x_(k-1)
```

EDIT:  An example for latitude would be that **x_k** would be the current latitude from the GPS and **x_(k-1)** would be the previous value of latitude.  The value of **b** is a percentage that you choose and you can tune **b** to get the desired smoothing.  I would start with **b = 0.2**.  Essentially, this will take 80% of the current latitude and add it to 20% of the previous latitude for the resultant **x_k** (display latitude) value.

Comment: TreyA: Thanks! can you please elaborate about the variables?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you are looking for. The two most common algorithms is the Douglas-Puecker algrothim and Vertex Reduction. I personally preffer vertex reduction as it's simpler, faster and I find the results to be more visually appealing. I have a blog post on this method here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/vertex-reductionone-of-my-secret-weapons/